# Search file in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I use xcode search to quick open files in project. It works very good when the files are in current project, but when I have one project that includes other sub-projects it searches only in files from current project. Is it possible to search a file in all files from all sub-projects?
I don't like to open a sub-project every time when I want to search a file that is not included in main project.

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In xcode on left pane in the project navigator at the bottom there is a search field. In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/AbouttheNavigatorArea/AbouttheNavigatorArea.html) it is called filter bar.

According to [Inder Kumar Rathore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21598869/956397) the shortcut is  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

[image: project navigator, filter bar]

Also see [xcode: search by file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332262/xcode-search-by-file)

Comment: I always forget this feature. It's really handy when you have tons of files and can't find where they are in the hierarchy. Sometimes I have to track down old resources that I want to remove from my apps to reduce the file sizes.

Answer (score 51):

Shortcut to search a file <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

To go to line number in a file use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the difference between a project and a sub-project, but `Shift+Cmd+F` will bring up the search whose scope is everything included in the project window and not just the active file. If you are talking about linked files in other projects, I think you're still stuck opening those projects to search.

Comment: I don't want to search in files, I want to search files. And Shift+Cmd+F searches only in current project files, not in all files.
I have project that contains other projects that are compiled as static libraries. I want to search inside that projects too.

Answer (score 0):

You could include the source in your project without copying it or adding it to the target.

Or have a look at XCode 4 if you are a registered developer.

Comment: That means to modify my project and I don't want to do this:) I know that few years ago I could search in sub-projects too. I don't know who was the guy that configured xcode... And I don't work with same team:(

Comment: How exactly do you search for files? And what do you add to your project? If it's just the compiled lib, how should Xcode know about anything of other sources?

Comment: Ok, I'll explain in Visual Studio terms:P
I have a solution(main project) that contains all the other projects and main application source file. When I search a file, xcode searches only in the files included in Solution instead of searching in Solution files and project files like in Visual Studio, so before every search I must open the correct project and search in it.

Comment: There's are options to search in included files or search in files and folders (which you can specify). Look in the Batch Find Options: Hit the "Options..." button in the Project Find pane.

Answer (score 0):

The search pane in XCode 4.2 has a 'Find in' section which includes the checkbox []And linked frameworks.

If (and only if) your framework dependencies are on the library's project file, and not on the library binaries, this will search both headers and source of the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

On the search field, search the name of your file. Then when you find it, right click on it and select "Reveal in Project Navigator"