# Xcode search by file or class name

Tags: xcode

I would like to search for all .xib files in a particular xcode project but I don't know how to do this on xcode. Also, suppose I want to search for a particular file, e.g. Test.h, how do I do this? I know how to do this using linux, but that gives the structure of the filesystem, and not of the xcode project.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In xcode on left pane at the bottom there is a search field, just type xib, it should list all xib files. Same with other type of searches as well.

Place your cursor in this "Filter" with a keyboard shortcut:
<kbd>⌥</kbd> +<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> , or by choosing from the File Menu <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Filter</kbd> > <kbd>Filter in Navigator</kbd>

[image: like this]

**Edit:**

You can even use wildcards. For e.g., *m*1.x* will filter SampleXib1.xib, It's also incase-sensitive.

Comment: The `Edit > Filter > Filter in Navigator` doesn't seem to focus this textfield as I would expect it to. I'd expect it to focus the textfield in the same way as `Find > Find in Project`. Hoping to find a hotkey...

Answer (score 37):

To search a file/class <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (Command + Shift + O)

To See the current opened file in Project Navigator <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

To go to line number in a file use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Note: This partially answers the question, to see all `.xib` you can search it in project navigator as mentioned by one of the answers. But I think these shortcuts are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Type your search keyword in the text field at the very bottom of the Project Navigator pane on the left.

[image: File search in Project Navigator]